# Grunt doesnt compile codes if subtasks are used

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, typescript

I am new at using Grunt :) I have study documentation and found very interesting problem. 
If I have task defined like this :

```
    typescript: {
         options: {
                target: 'es5',
                expand: true
            },
            base: {
                src: ['src/main/webapp/**/*.ts'],
                dest: ''
            }
    }
    grunt.registerTask('compile', ['typescript']);
```

Everything is fine. But if i want to specify target, to have a more build phases, so i write the code like this:

```
     typescript: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                target: 'es5',
                expand: true
            },
            base: {
                src: ['src/main/webapp/**/*.ts'],
                dest: ''
            }
        }
     }
     grunt.registerTask('compile', ['typescript:dev']);
```

Than no error occured, but TS files are not compiled to JS files, becouse grunt didnt find any TS files. I realy dont know, what iam doing wrong....

Any idea? :) Please..i am realy desperate :(

Comment: A quick look at the [docs](https://github.com/k-maru/grunt-typescript) suggests that subtasks might not be available with this module.

Comment: You are genius! I have thought, that the structure of Grundfile depend on Grunt and not on plugins...very good notion! Please write your comment as answer and then i will check as right answer :)

Comment: @Xrew `grunt-ts` supports subtasks just fine : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts

Comment: Yes, I know, it was the next option i have tried after @Andy wrote me, that Tyepscript doesnt work. :) But thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look at the [documentation](https://github.com/k-maru/grunt-typescript) suggests that subtasks might not be available with this module.